# How can use Type Checker get Interface or Class extends type

Tags: typescript

example code:

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    breed: string;
}

interface DataProps {
    color?: string;
}

interface DogProps extends DataProps {
    type?: "Beagle" | "Sheepdog"；
}
```

in `Class` extends I can use check extends names:

```
const symbol = this.checker.getSymbolAtLocation((<ts.ClassDeclaration> node).name);
const extendsDocEntry = "declarations" in symbol? symbol.declarations.map((declaration: any) => (
    "expression" in declaration && declaration.expression.text
)).filter((extendsName: any) => extendsName) : void 0;
```

but i do not know if this is the correct code.
and i still don't know how get  `Interface` extends.

Please help me solve this problem, very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at `ts.ClassLikeDeclaration` it has a `heritageClauses` property. This property will be not undefined and contain an array of objects that are `ts.HeritageClause`.

For each individual heritage clause, you can check the `token` property to see if it's `ts.SyntaxKind.ExtendsKeyword` or `ts.SyntaxKind.ImplementsKeyword`. From there, you can look at the `types` property to get all the expressions with type arguments.

Once you have the expression and type arguments, you should be able to use `this.checker.getSymbolAtLocation(...)` to get the symbol of what is being extended or `this.typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(...)` to get the type.

Here's some simple untested code to help you get started... obviously you would probably want to loop over these arrays and check `heritageClause.token` like I described above:

```
const classDeclaration = node as ts.ClassDeclaration;
const firstHeritageClause = classDeclaration.heritageClauses![0];
const firstHeritageClauseType = firstHeritageClause.types![0];

const extendsSymbol = this.checker.getSymbolAtLocation(firstHeritageClauseType.expression);
const extendsType = this.checker.getTypeAtLocation(firstHeritageClauseType.expression);
```

For `ts.InterfaceDeclaration`, it's pretty much the same deal. There's also a `heritageClauses` array.